# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function, discord bot

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I'm a beginner at learning anything code. But I'm coding a Discord bot for fun and i'm trying to give it the "clear" message command but, when i run it, it give's me a message saying:

Process exited with code 1
Uncaught /Users/ayo/Desktop/verde copy/draft.js:10
await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then(messages => {
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Here's my code:

```
const args = message.content.split('.clear').slice(1);
const amount = args.join(' '); 

if (!amount) return msg.reply('You haven\'t given an amount of messages which should be deleted!');
if (isNaN(amount)) return msg.reply('The amount parameter isn`t a number!'); 

if (amount > 100) return msg.reply('You can`t delete more than 100 messages at once!'); 
if (amount < 1) return msg.reply('You have to delete at least 1 message!'); 

await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount }).then(messages => {
    msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages
)});
```

I'm aware it's about a async function but don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: the error is basically telling you what you need to do

Comment: Remove `await`. You're not using it.

Comment: @meagar am i supposed to replace it with something else?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to wrap your code in an `async` *immediately executed function expression* (IIFE):

```
(async function() {
     // your code goes here
})();
```

That said, in this code *as written* there's no need for you to `await` the `.fetch` call at all.

If you wanted to use `async` "consistently" you wouldn't use a Promise chain:

```
let messages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: amount });
await msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```